# How to listen the Android's onActivityResult method

Tags: android, flutter

I tried to use a new camera's activity to capture a image, but the activity's result method not work in my case.

```
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware, PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener {

  private void launchTakeImageWithCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File imageFile = createTemporaryWritableImageFile();
//    Uri pendingCameraMediaUri = Uri.parse("file:" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity, "com.example.dcc_flutter_ai.FileProvider", imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    grantUriPermissions(intent, imageUri);

    try {
      activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);
    ...
  }


  // This method not work in my case.
  @Override
  public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID:
        handleCaptureResult(resultCode, data);
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should first have told that the camera app comes up and that the user can take a picture.

Comment: Yes, I hide the request permission code before `launchTakeImageWithCameraIntent`.

Comment: ?????????? Why dont you just answer my comment? I dont understand your response.

Comment: Sorry, I just show my question related code above, not all you need.

Comment: ???? You posted enough code. I need no extra code. I just would like you to answer my comment. It looks to me you dont understand my comment. Try to read it again and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

here below code will help you to listen the onActivityResult method

```
  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    activity = binding.getActivity();
    binding.addActivityResultListener(this);
    binding.addOnNewIntentListener(this); 

  }
```

Don't forget to implements `ActivityAware` for your class

Comment: but this way is deprecated  for listen to onactivityresult 
there is a new way for listen to activity try search about registerForActivityResult